# Replace the sentence include some text with Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to strip the sentence containing words `"…Read more"` in a paragraph with Python RE. E.g. to transform the content from

```
'AAA. BBB. CCC. DDD …Read more'
```

to simply

```
'AAA. BBB. CCC.'
```

Just strip the unfinished sentence ends with `"…Read more"`.
This procedure is for crawler result cleaning purpose as you can tell.

I have tried the code below

```
paragraph=re.sub('[.] .*?…Read more$','',paragraph)
```

The result I am getting now is only `'AAA'`. I want to keep the content until the last unfinished sentence.

Comment: Shouldn't you need `'AAA. BBB. CCC. DDD'` as output?

Comment: Why not just `paragraph.replace('…Read more', '')` ?

Comment: Hi Austin. The sentence DDD is unfinished. So I have to chop the whole thing off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To strip the unfinished sentence ends with "…Read more", you can match not a dot using a negated character class `[^.]*` and then match `…Read more` at the end `$` of the string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jmUyYs/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZbfVUA)

```
import re
paragraph = "AAA. BBB. CCC. DDD …Read more"
paragraph=re.sub('[^.]*…Read more$','',paragraph)
print(paragraph)
```

Result

```
AAA. BBB. CCC.
```

Comment: Think you have nailed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you capture the group you want to preserve then you can specify that group to remain after the substitution:

```
 paragraph = re.sub('(.*)…Read more$', r'\1', paragraph)
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. Could you pls specify how to remain the sentences I wanna keep?

Answer (score 0):

> strip the sentence containing words "…Read more"

This includes the DDD, right? Since your example shows that.

This basically means you want to strip everything after the last period.

```
".".join(text.split(".")[:-1])+"."
```

Explanation:

- `text.split(".")` splits the string at the period. It results in `['AAA', ' BBB', ' CCC', ' DDD …Read more']` (`…` is another character, not literally three dots)
- `text.split(".")[:-1]` takes the above list without the last element
- `".".join(text.split(".")[:-1])` joins the remaining elements on the period (puts that separator between the elements). Making it `AAA. BBB. CCC`
- finally, we add the last period using `+"."`

**EDIT**

```
result = ".".join(text.split(".")[:-1])+"." if "Read more" in text[-10:] else text
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! However, not every entry my crawler's delivered contains "…Read more". It only occurs when the content is too long. Stripping with your solution would chop off the last sentence of every entry, no matter whether the "…Read more" occurs.

Comment: @NickZhou Added edit with checking for `Read more` in last 10 characters ("Read more" is literally 9 characters, but in case there's `…` afterwards). If there is, it cuts the last part. If not, the result is the same as original `text`